Is this homebrew Warlock patron - the DM - balanced?
My daughter's been dabbling into some homebrew for D&D 5th Edition - this is her first completed unit of new content. She was amused by the idea of a Warlock having the DM as their "Otherworldly Patron". I'm sure this isn't the first such, but she's interested in knowing if it looks reasonably balanced.
To my eye, it's not bad. Master's Knowledge looks strong - it was originally switched with Plot Armour, but I argued they should change places - but the effect is the same as Critical Role's Monk of the Cobalt Soul's 3rd level ability (3 levels earlier, but gated on a Flurry of Blows attack landing). The pact boon I think may be pushing it.
(FWIW, as the post author, rather than the implicit CC BY-SA 4.0. licence held by me, this subclass is CC BY-NC-SA 4.0. held by my daughter)

Warlock patron: The DM
Your patron is a puppet-master deity with control over the world around you. You
understand that the events that befall you and the people you meet are controlled by
the DM, the happenings are controlled by dice, and the whole world is understood
like a book of rules by your patron.
Expanded Spell List
The DM lets you choose from an expanded list of spells when you learn a warlock
spell. The following spells are added to the warlock spell list for you.
DM expanded spell list



Spell level
Spells




1st
Disguise self, identify


2nd
Borrowed knowledge, detect thoughts


3rd
Bestow curse, sending


4th
Confusion, fabricate


5th
Dominate person, modify memory



Plot armour
Starting at 1st level, your patron has a fondness for you that means you can
circumvent the chosen narrative in order to stay alive. You learn the shield spell, and
can cast it once per day without expending a spell slot. This does not count against
the number of warlock spells you know.
Additionally, when you succeed on a death saving throw, you become immediately
stabilised with one hit point. You cannot use this feature again until you finish a long
rest.
Master’s knowledge
Starting at 6th level, you can use your patron’s encompassing knowledge of the
world to better understand your enemies. As a bonus action, you can ask your
patron for information on a creature you can see. You learn all of its damage
vulnerabilities, damage resistances, damage immunities, and condition immunities,
as well as whether it’s hit point total is higher or lower than yours. You can do this a
number of times per day equal to your charisma modifier.
Rule-bending
Beginning at 10th level, you can use your close understanding of the rules of the
multiverse to bend them around yourself. As an action, you can choose one skill or
tool; for 10 minutes, you have proficiency with the chosen skill or tool. You cannot
use this feature again until you finish a long rest.
Additionally, when you cast a warlock spell, you can change the damage type to any
other damage type. You may do this a number of times equal to your warlock level
divided by three (rounded down). You regain all uses of this feature when you complete a long rest.
Rocks fall, everybody dies
When you reach 14th level, you can call upon and channel the rage of your patron.
Once per day, you can call forth rocks to drop from the sky within 120 feet of you.
These rocks fall in a 10ft radius circle, and all creatures must make a dexterity
saving throw against your warlock spell DC or take 8d10 bludgeoning damage, or
half as much on a successful save.
New pact boon: Pact of the die
(prerequisite: DM as patron)

You are gifted a twenty-sided die as a representation of your patron; it is no
larger than your palm, and looks however you wish it. You can use this as
your spellcasting focus. This die has a number of uses equal to your
proficiency bonus, and regains all expended uses at dawn.
You may expend one use of the die to give yourself advantage on an attack
roll, ability check, or saving throw; to give another creature disadvantage on
an attack roll, ability check, or saving throw; or to roll two damage dice and
choose which value to use.
Should your die be lost, you can perform a 1-hour ritual to receive a new one
from your patron, which can be done during a short rest. Your die ceases to
exist if you die, or perform the 1-hour ritual to summon a new one.


Seems a bit weak
To me, this seems a bit weak. The abilities are mostly ribbons without that much actual impact on the game.
Plot Armor
One extra spell with a free cast every day. Shield is a good spell normally not available to Warlocks, but otherwise I find this to be underwhelming when compared to other patrons that get actual abilities.
Stabilizing on a successful Death Save is mostly a ribbon unless your campaign is particularly brutal.
Master's Knowledge
Very situational. If you fight a lot of unknown enemies with vulnerabilities and resistances that you can't figure out by fighting it it's useful. In my experience, this would give very little actual value.
Rule Bending
The proficiency part is again situational. It might come up and be useful, but most parties have the necessary proficiencies covered.
Changing damage types is also very situational. Order of the Scribe Wizards get this at level 2, but without any limits on using it and a lot of other stuff as well. One big difference is that Rule Bending as written also works on cantrips. I would consider removing the usage limit and possibly change it to only work with leveled spells. Eldritch Blast is very rarely resisted anyway though, so having it work for cantrips might not actually impact the game all that much.
Rocks fall, everyone dies
This is strong as written, since it doesn't say that it requires any kind of action. Hurl through Hell is similar, but it requires you to hit with an attack first, only affects one creature and removes them from combat for a round. I think this ability is fine.
Pact of the Die
This is probably a bit too strong. It's similar to the optional Pact of the Talisman, but the talisman only works for ability checks. The advantage of the talisman however is that you can use it after failing; Pact of the Die must be used before the roll. The ability to grant a target disadvantage on their save against your spells is very strong though.
I would change the wording of the damage roll part, since you could have more than one die. Something like "roll damage twice and choose which result to use". It should also be clarified when this reroll applies. Can it be used for spells like fireball?

Thanks - she has some thoughts for adjustments; we'll either comment here or repost, depending on the scale of the changes.

+1 agree Great shout that Pact of the Die (not dice, as it's only one) is a bit too strong and that the rocks falling effect needs further clarification.

Immediate comment, while I wait for more full changes: would it materially help weaken Pact of the Die if the damage reroll were removed? Or is that just small change compared to the Adv/Disadv?

@Chowlett I think that's the weakest part of it. I would rather remove saving throws.

Thanks; I've posted an updated version as a new question
